# An admin area with inputs for changing the cat's name, url, and number of clicks (hidden by default)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I create an HTML form with Admin Button and in the `.js` file I wrote a `click` Event in Admin Button to change from:

```
style='display:none'
```

to:

```
style='display:block'
```

but it's not working. Why?

```
var adminMode = { 
  init: function() {
    this.adminButton = document.getElementById('admin-button');
    this.adminForm = document.getElementById('admin-form');// form ID   
    this.allForm = document.getElementById('all-form'); //div ID

    this.adminButton.addEventListener('click', function (allForm) {
      this.adminForm.style.display = 'inline'
    });
  },
```

**HTML**

```
<button id='admin-button'>Admin</button> <br><br> 
<div id='all-form'> 
 <form id='admin-form' style='display:none'> 
   Name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="firstname" value=" "> <br><br>
   Img URL:<br> 
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value=" "> <br><br> 
    <button> Save</button>  
    <button>Cancel</button> 
 </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: inline OR block it's all to show the form

Comment: you want when click `adminButton` display will be `block` ???

Comment: can you please send the form?

Comment: Also can you please send the full code?

Comment: this.adminForm is not working in click event function

Comment: just a tip. If you create an admin area that is hidden. you need to know that everyone can access it just by hitting 'F12', finding the element and changing it css to display block, not needing to click anywhere or make any login.

Comment: @smith More specifically, with what is saying, is that using `display: block` just makes things invisible, but they are still there. You should use server-side code to prevent them from rendering if you want to block users. In ASP.Net this is setting `Visible=False`, in [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196694/apply-css-displaynone-or-use-iffalsecontent-to-block-content-at-clients)/MVC you can wrap the HTML in an If block.

Comment: @AnkitParmar thank you so much.. but still not working :( that's my HTML for more info : <button id='admin-button'>Admin</button>
<br><br>
<div id='all-form'>
   <form id='admin-form' style='display:none'>
     Name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="firstname" value=" ">
     <br><br>
     Img URL:<br>
     <input type="text" name="lastname" value=" ">
     <br><br>
     <button> Save</button>
     <button>Cancel</button>
   </form>
</div>

Comment: @לבנימלכה yes exactly

Comment: @smith see my edit

Comment: @לבנימלכה Please add a decent comment to your suggested edit. It's fine to add code from the comments to the answer, but people who don't know it comes from the comments might reject it otherwise.

Comment: @Ivar of course you right but I edited the question before post it in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var adminMode = {  init: function() {      
    this.adminButton = document.getElementById('admin-button');   
    //this.adminForm =   document.getElementById('admin-form');// form ID
    //this.allForm =  document.getElementById('all-form'); //div ID 
    this.adminButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        document.getElementById('admin-form').style.display = 'inline'   
});

},
```

Comment: this.adminForm is not working in click event function

Comment: thank you so much.. but still not working :( that's my HTML for more info : <button id='admin-button'>Admin</button>
<br><br>
<div id='all-form'>
   <form id='admin-form' style='display:none'>
     Name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="firstname" value=" ">
     <br><br>
     Img URL:<br>
     <input type="text" name="lastname" value=" ">
     <br><br>
     <button> Save</button>
     <button>Cancel</button>
   </form>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

**That what you mean**

```
 init: function() {
    document.getElementById('admin-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
          document.getElementById('allForm').style.display = 'block';  
     });
    }
```

**OR** `admin-form`

```
 init: function() {
    document.getElementById('admin-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
          document.getElementById('admin-form').style.display = 'block';  
     });
    }
```

If you write `function()` the `this` is not known....  
**For your Edit:** put the `function` in `script` no `init()`

```js
function dispaly(){
  document.getElementById('admin-form').style.display = 'block';  
}
```

```html
<button id='admin-button' onclick="dispaly()">Admin</button> <br><br> 
<div id='all-form'> 
 <form id='admin-form' style='display:none'> 
   Name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="firstname" value=" "> <br><br>
   Img URL:<br> 
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value=" "> <br><br> 
    <button> Save</button>  
    <button>Cancel</button> 
 </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: Tell me for more help :)

Comment: thank you so much.. but still not working :( that's my HTML for more info : <button id='admin-button'>Admin</button>
<br><br>
<div id='all-form'>
   <form id='admin-form' style='display:none'>
     Name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="firstname" value=" ">
     <br><br>
     Img URL:<br>
     <input type="text" name="lastname" value=" ">
     <br><br>
     <button> Save</button>
     <button>Cancel</button>
   </form>
</div>

Comment: @smith Tell me for help

Comment: @smith I really appricate if you mark as answer (green v)